# How to use D3 scale to convert a continuous domain to a range of ordinal dates?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got a continuous set of values from 0 to 1, and would like to map this in the most convenient way to my data, which has 365 dates (each one is formatted as "%Y-%m-%d"). It seemed simple enough before I got started, or maybe it's way too late to be using my head, but I'm getting nowhere.

I've tried

```
 d3.scale.linear()
         .domain([0,1])
         .range(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.date;}));
```

and

```
d3.time.scale()
       .domain([0,1])
       .range(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.date;}));
```

both of which give output like `1423737864000` (although, at least, this number varies depending on the scale's input).

I've also tried

```
d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain([0,1])
        .range(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return d.date;}));
```

but this only gives me my first date, `Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)` as output, irrespective of inputs.

Basically, instead of using `d3.time.scale.domain()` with dates and  `d3.time.scale.domain()` with values, can I using **values** in the domain and the **dates** that I've got in my data as the range?

**EDIT** does it help that I've got the dates arranged in order, beginning with Jan 1 and ending with Dec 31?

Comment: i think you should be using `d3.time.scale()` and what you passing in domain should be in range and viceversa.

Comment: @Cyril sorry, what do you mean? Why do you think I should be doing that, when I specifically said my scenario involves using 0,1 as the range and the dates as the domain?

Comment: I think scrollex it would be best if you can make a fiddle ..coz may be many people like me may not be able to understand the real issue..

Comment: @cyril You're totally right, good idea; I'll get a chance to do so later today and will update the question/tag you in the comment when I do. Thanks!

Comment: `.range` is the pixel space of your plot.  Passing dates into that function makes little sense.  `.domain` is the *user space* of your plot.  Are you attempting to plot dates on one axis and your values from 0 to 1 on another axis?